# (Accepted) answer to a spam question - bot account?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a question which was apparently spam but was answered by a high profile user (and accepted as the answer). I was wondering what's going on? My first guess would be that the user in question (the one providing the answer) is (at least for this answer) just a bot. Here's the screen shot (the questions URL is/was https://superuser.com/questions/1471367):

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### I noticed a question which was apparently spam but was answered by a high profile user

The spammer edited his question 17 minutes after it was posted and replaced a valid question with spam.

Screenshot of original question as posted:

[image]

The original question was answered 4 minutes before it was edited.

Comment: The community took care of the post, but the OP has 1 rep, so was unaffected by the 100 pt rep penalty.  They are clearly here just to cause mischief and to spam their "services".  Wouldn't it be appropriate to apply some kind of sanction (like account termination, or at least suspension)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I would have thought the spam deletion & -8 rep would auto-generate some kind of at least temp ban. I've seen bans posted as banners on user account profiles before now, but maybe that's a 20/25k rep feature. I'm only 18k on this stack.

Comment: @fixer1234 Spammer has now been nuked.

Comment: That warms the cockles of my heart.  There's nothing quite like warm cockles.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 - for a true 'interwebz' perspective, it should warm the *cookies* of your heart. There's certainly nothing like warm cookies ;-))

Comment: Since it is a valid question, can't the question be undeleted and the spam be redacted?

Comment: @gparyani Too late. In any case the OP probably posted it with the intention of adding spam later so question was not posted in good faith.

Comment: @gparyani - Reverting to the earlier revision and undeleting would still leave the spam info in the revision history. You could instead repost the (original) question yourself if you think it's worth keeping? (Probably clean it up first). You could even reach out to Spiff (who posted the answer) to see if they want to move it across themselves.

Comment: @Robotnik Which is why I suggested redacting the spam from the revision history.

Comment: @gparyani ah, missed that at the end of the sentence there haha. In either case - it's definitely an option to repost it yourself.